# Do we still refer to a threat as a threat once it has been realised?

Tags: terminology, threats

A threat is defined as something that might do harm but once a threat happens do we still refer to it as a threat?

For instance, if malware infects our computer, do we still refer to the malware as a threat?

Comment: If malware infects your computer do you no longer see it as a threat? Because I do.

Comment: @baconface, personally I would call it an incident.

Comment: a rose by any other name would smell so sweet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for 'breach'.  As described below, the original threat remains, a breach has occurred, and additional new unmitigated threats may exist where the attacker may be able to do additional damage now that they're inside.

**Threat**: the possibility that something could try to happen

**Threat Actor**: the person or other entity who will try to make the bad thing (threat) happen

**Vulnerability**: a hole in the design of the defenses that may allow a threat actor to cause a threat to happen

**Asset**: something of value

**Exposure**: an asset has been placed behind a vulnerability, thereby exposing the data to the threat

**Exploit** (n): the mechanism by which the threat actor will make use of the vulnerability to get to the exposed asset

**Exploit** (v): the act of using an exploit (n) to make use of a vulnerability to access the exposed asset

**Breach**(v): the successful act of exploiting a vulnerability. Breaching the defenses

**Breach**(n): the event during which a breach(v) occurred. A breach in the defenses.

**incident**: a detected breach or exposure. In some environments, a detected vulnerability, without an exposure

**Mitigate**: to reduce the severity of an actual or potential breach

**Control** something in place to mitigate, detect, or prevent a breach

Note that a threat that successfully breaches the security of some of your assets may not have successfully accessed all your assets, and may attempt to re-enter at a later time. Thus, you have a breach by an ongoing threat, with possibility of a wider or repeated breach, using one or more exploits to exploit one or more vulnerabilities that exposed one or more assets to the threat of a threat agent.

Comment: Thank you for your really good answer. Maybe a small point of disagreement. For me a threat, is an entity or an event that might harm the organization's assets. Hence organizations deal every day with threats (malware, social engineering, web application attacks, ...). So threat happens but control measures prevent them from causing harm.

Comment: @yusuf definitions do vary. Mine are drawn in large part from NIST, but individual organizations use the terms that communicate stuff best to their employees, customers and regulators.

Answer (score -1):

A threat has nothing to with a malware. It is basically a certain probability that an vulnerability gets exposed.

A malware is an exploited vulnerability by some kind.